# Mokafive Host Script reporting

Tags: batch-file, vbscript, reporting

I'm working on setting up Host Scripts for Mokafive player on Windows. I've made a few VBSCripts and have worked with batch files trying to gather information on Mokafive Player start. I'm trying to capture data such as Firewall status, and Encryption status. I've tried multiple variations on gathering this data back to the Mokafive Management Server, such as echoing the results out in VBScrpt, Echoing the results back into the .bat file needed to run the VBScript, with no success.

Does anyone have any code, or examples of a working Host Script for Mokafive Player?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After meeting with several engineers it looks like the VBScript must echo out the results from each condition to an output file. This file will then be read by the launcher XML as a key value pair and parsed out to the database. so per each line that needs to be output you'd use the following...

```
Set objfs = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
outputfile = "outputfile.out
Set objFile = objfs.CreateTextFile(outputfile,True)
'Your Script Here
objFile.Write "Key=" & "Value" & vbNewLine
```